# Is eval() harmful if used for simple maths equations in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it harmful to use eval() for simple codes like evaluation of a simple math question:

```js
rZ1 = 2
rZ2 = 9
var op1 = ["/"];

T = document.getElementById("T");
    
ans = eval(rZ1 + op1 + rZ2).toFixed(3);

T.innerHTML=ans;
```

```html
<label id="T"> </label>
```

Comment: Don't think so, it works fine - but do make sure it doesn't contain characters *other* than those on a whitelist (digits and arithmetic operators)

Comment: The danger of `eval` is when the argument comes from an untrusted source. If you're creating the argument yourself and you know it's safe, it's OK.

Comment: Why are you concatenating an array? `op1` should be a string. It happens to work because the array is converted to a string, and converting an array produces a string with all the elements separated by commas. When there's one element it's the same as that element.

Comment: Barmar and CertainPerformance have got it covered. I'll throw in a little more - even if you can trust the source of, especially, the operator, I'd be strongly in favor of checking the operator and using that to control your logic. Thus, something like if (op1 == "/") { ans = rz1 / rz2; } else if (op1 == "*") { ans = rz1 * rz2; } else if (op1 == "%") { ans = rz1 % rz2; } _and so forth_. Then your eval can't run away some unexpected direction, possibly due to a typo.